# Find an example where there is a variable that affects the result, unlike expected

Tags: soft-question, examples-counterexamples, big-list

I don't know if this site is a suitable place to look for examples, but I have a lot of ideas that I would like to find a good example of, and I try to organize these things in a later book. I hope I get to a place where I can discuss my thoughts so that I find people taking these questions seriously, and I think they are thoughts of many people.

I am searching for an interesting example/example of a theorem, issue or case in mathematics, in which there is a specific variable that affects the result, while the intuition tells that the result is independent of this variable.

In other words, I would like a case where intuition fails to estimate the effect of a factor on a particular problem and one thinks it is ineffective, while reality is otherwise.

Are you welcome to find examples of searching for examples on this site?

Comment: For a real world problem, I'd suggest the [Low birth weight paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_birth-weight_paradox#:~:text=The%20low%20birth%2Dweight%20paradox,weight%20children%20of%20non%2Dsmokers.).  For a more abstract problem, I like [this example](http://www.yichijin.com/files/elchanan.pdf)

Comment: The [Alabama apportionment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apportionment_paradox#:~:text=An%20example%20of%20the%20apportionment,this%20would%20decrease%20Alabama's%20seats) is another good example of a real world illustration.  Or the [Breiss paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braess%27s_paradox)

Comment: I'm looking for abstract math problems, and for the example link you're telling me it's an abstract problem it doesn't open for me, if you can point to another link or write the thread in an answer.

Comment: Well, of course each of the real world problems can be abstracted (and Breiss is typically phrased abstractly anyway).  [here](https://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2017/09/07/tyi-30-expected-number-of-dice-throws/) is another reference to the abstract one i mentioned, and the direct link to the paper I mentioned is http://www.yichijin.com/files/elchanan.pdf

Comment: As with low birth weight, the problem is that you are using a filter which you don't think is correlated to the thing you are testing, but which is.  The "abstract" one asks for the expected number of tosses it takes to see a $6$ given that only even numbers are observed.  The obvious answer, $3$, is wrong because the conditioning filter (only seeing even numbers) is correlated to observing  a short sequence.